# Second page in flutter naviagtion flow is not full size

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to make a basic "new activity" in flutter

I have followed the [flutters docs](https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics/) and made a button that navigates to the next page with:

```
Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> new HomePage(title: title,)));
```

This is the build method of the 2nd page/activity (HomePage.dart)

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Home"),
          textTheme: orbitTextTheme),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Container(
          color: Color.orange,
          height: 150.0,
          width: 150.0,
          child:new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Try to type?"
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _newReg,
        tooltip: 'New reg', //externalize
        backgroundColor: Color.orange,
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
```

BUT, the second page is not full size: (Notice the missing floating action button)
[image: flutter screenshot]
Can anyone tell me what am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
Was calling the `Navigator.push(` in a callback from googleSignIn (which presents a modal). So putting in a small delay fixed the bug. Thanks!

Comment: Your issue is not in the code you provided

Comment: That graphical bug happens whenever you pop the last visible route then push a new one

Comment: @Rémi is that what I am doing? As I see it, I am only pushing to the view stack?

Comment: @RémiRousselet You are right! I was making the push within a method that signed in to google. This caused a pop just before my push, which correlates to your comment. Feel free to submit it as an answer, and i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This graphical bug happens whenever you pop the **last** visible route before pushing a new one.

Consider using `pushReplacement` or `pushReplacementNamed` instead.